# Transaction with Paypal in Braintree

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, paypal, braintree

I have implemented braintree in my project.I have used javascript on client-side and .net on server side.I am using custom form integration to use paypal vault.i have done transaction. The payment is authorised and is submitted for settlement.But now i am unable to capture a successful payment transaction in my controller code.How can i do this?

Comment: Webhooks are for Subscription. What i am asking is how to capture Single successful Transaction using Paypal Vault?

Comment: There are about 5 different subscription webhooks.  One is for a successful transaction on a subscription.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I am not doing a subscription. I am doing a single transaction.

Comment: Okay, there's also a webhook for "Transaction: Disbursed"...  not one of the subscription webhooks.

Comment: .. but which method are you calling?  If you call `submit_for_settlement` don't you get a result object back with the details?

Comment: In my sandbox account the transaction is shown as authorized, the submitted for settlement then settling.So at C# coding it is not sending a Transaction Settled or Successfull Payment Status.

Comment: Try contacting their support email.  They're pretty good at responding.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

You can use our [disbursement webhooks](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/disbursement/dotnet). These will provide you with a list of transaction ids that were disbursed to your merchant account as part of this disbursement. If this does not solve your problem, I suggest you reach out to our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for more help.